# promises chain result if nothing rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, angular-promise

I have a chain of promises, where I use catch to catch errors.

```
this.load()
    .then(self.initialize)
    .then(self.close)
    .catch(function(error){
        //error-handling
    })
```

What function gets called if the chain has finished without rejection?
I was using finally, but this gets called also if an error occurs.
I'd like to call a function after the catch-function which gets only called if no promise was rejected.

I'm using node.js with the q - module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding another then will do.

```
this.load()
    .then(self.initialize)
    .then(self.close)
    .then(function() {
      //Will be called if nothing is rejected
      //for sending response or so
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        //error-handling
    })
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 and Mannu, both answers work. Thx alot :)

Answer (score 3):

I would change your `.catch()` to be a `.then()` and supply both an onFullfill and an onRejected handler.  Then you can determine exactly which one happened and your code is very clear that one or the other will execute.

```
this.load()
    .then(self.initialize)
    .then(self.close)
    .then(function() {
         // success handling
     }, function(error){
        //error-handling
     });
```

FYI, this isn't the only way to do things.  You could also use `.then(fn1).catch(fn2)` which would similarly call fn1 or fn2 based on what the promise state was prior except that both could get called if fn1 returned a rejected promise or threw an exception because that would also be handled by fn2.

Comment: Only one or the other? [Not exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi - As best I can tell, my first example IS "one or the other".  The second example could be both, if `fn1` throws or returns a rejected promise.

Comment: Yeah, it was the "and" in your phrasing that set me off.